# How to save to an excel file

Tags: java, excel, save

I am trying to save an excel file but for some reason I cannot save it. Here is the error i get while opening the saved file

"Excel cannot open the file [filename] because the file format or file extension is not valid."

Here is the code i am using to save to the excel file it is definitely a .xlsx what am i doing incorrect?

```
public static void saveFile(int lineCoutner, String Closed, Elements ticketNumber, String College, String customerCalled, String firstResponse, String ResolutionTime){

    try {
        String filename = "C:/Users/ross/Desktop/Work/Ticketing.xlsx";
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("FirstSheet");  

        HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short)0);
        rowhead.createCell(0).setCellValue("Ticket");
        rowhead.createCell(1).setCellValue("Reason for Contact");
        rowhead.createCell(2).setCellValue("Resolution OutCome");
        rowhead.createCell(3).setCellValue("TimeCustomerCalled");
        rowhead.createCell(4).setCellValue("First Reponse");
        rowhead.createCell(5).setCellValue("Time Resolution");
        rowhead.createCell(6).setCellValue("College");

        HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short)1);
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(ticketNumber.text());
        row.createCell(1).setCellValue(Closed);
        row.createCell(2).setCellValue(Closed);
        row.createCell(3).setCellValue(customerCalled);
        row.createCell(4).setCellValue(firstResponse);
        row.createCell(5).setCellValue(ResolutionTime);
        row.createCell(6).setCellValue(College);

        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
        System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated!");

    } catch ( Exception ex ) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about Java, but on PHP if something is wrong with your variables values, the file is generated but corrupted since the script didn't run as it should. Maybe debugging each variable which is used on `setCellValue` method?

Comment: @FabianoAraujo Looks like java to me.

Comment: Ross, your title and your question do not match.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yep, I realized it after posting it. But the meaning is the same. I changed my comment to a more generic one, quoting PHP behavior.

Comment: @Scary Wombat Sorry mate i realized as i posted it is that better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first text line on the HSSF website says:

> HSSF is the POI Project's pure Java implementation of the Excel '97(-2007) file format.

So .xlsx is the wrong extension.  Try .xls.  It is possible Excel is attempting to open it as a newer format file because of its extension, i.e., that it doesn't check for older formats, which would take up time and make it look slower than it needed to look for a purpose it doesn't really want to take up time for.

Answer (score 0):

**HSSF** is used for xsl files.
If you need xslx format, you should use **XSSF**.

Also, POI library uses a lot of memory when read/write files; so in case of OOM exception use SXSSF (streamed version of XSSF).

Good luck.